# Exclude specific rows in COPY command on RedShift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm using the COPY command to load a csv file from S3 into a Redshift table. It's a 5 million row file and I get a load error saying row 259123 has text instead of a number.

Is there an option to exclude that row when loading? I'm guessing there will be a few more like that so I'm looking for a way to exclude a set of specific rows from the import.

```
copy newtable from 's3://data.csv' credentials
'aws_access_key_id=ttt;aws_secret_access_key=ttt' 
delimiter ',' IGNOREHEADER as 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "ESCAPE maxerror error_count". Let say you want to escape 1 error then:

```
 copy newtable from 's3://data.csv' credentials
'aws_access_key_id=ttt;aws_secret_access_key=ttt' 
 delimiter ',' IGNOREHEADER as 1`ESCAPE maxerror 1
```

[Amazon redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror)

Comment: thanks, I just figured it out and saw your response. I used `maxerror as 5` per the docs and it works. Not sure what ESCAPE does but will look it up.

Comment: it escapes the special characters.